# Getting text from a clicked listview item

Tags: android, listview

My ListView is a list of recipes pulled from my database. I am trying to get the text of a clicked item in my ListView.  The ListView is populated through a database call and a cursoradapter.  I want to use the text of the selected item to make another database call in another activity. Here is the code chunk

```
listView.setClickable(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            final String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
            recipeid = myDBAdapter.getRecipeID(text);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListAllRecipes.this, DisplayRecipe.class);
            intent.putExtra("recipeid", recipeid);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
```

When I run my code, I get

```
04-22 14:08:37.022: E/AndroidRuntime(25206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 14:08:37.022: E/AndroidRuntime(25206): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
04-22 14:08:37.022: E/AndroidRuntime(25206):    at com.example.ketorecipes.ListAllRecipes$1.onItemClick(ListAllRecipes.java:47)
```

when I click on an item in the ListView.

Here is the Activity in one chunk:

```
public class ListAllRecipes extends Activity{
private DBAdapter myDBAdapter;
private ListView listView;
private int recipeid;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_all);



    myDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDBAdapter.openToRead();
    Cursor c = myDBAdapter.getValues();

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String[] from = new String[] {"_id"};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.name_entry};
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_entry, c, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);



    listView.setClickable(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            final String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
            recipeid = myDBAdapter.getRecipeID(text);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListAllRecipes.this, DisplayRecipe.class);
            intent.putExtra("recipeid", recipeid);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of casting underlying layout to ``TextView`` you should use ``v.findViewById(your_textview_id)`` to retrieve the text.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm still very new to Android, and I am not a very strong programmer to begin with. Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: I'm assuming you're populating the ListView with custom layouts, which are based on RelativeLayout? Now clicking the ListView will give you this layout main view as ``View`` parameter. But you can retrieve the underlying ``TextView`` by using View.findViewById(resource_id_assigned_for_TextView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You associate _id with R.id.name_entry, so your list consists of whatever the values of _id are.

```
String[] from = new String[] {"_id"};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.name_entry};
```

If that is so you can get the name which is _id by

```
Cursor c = cursorAdapter.getCursor();
String text = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

Comment: Thank you! I am successfully getting the string, now I just have to figure out where I screwed up my SQL!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the `position` Field `onItemClick` to get the item from `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` and that will return the entry that represents the item you just clicked (may need to cast to the proper type), that should be what you want, no need to manually get the value from the UI element.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that the returned view (v) isn't a textview.
your list items are customized views, so you need to get the view by finding the view by id.